# Backgrounding Phonegap and the relationship between Activity, Process, and Service life-cycles

Tags: android, cordova, activity-lifecycle

I have a Phonegap application and I want to run some procedures in the background. That is, perform some logic while the Phonegap Activity is not visible. For now, I cannot write a native Service to run these procedures, so I want the Phonegap Activity itself to act as a Service. Of course, the logic to be run as a Service is Javascript and cannot be implemented as a normal Android Service. One solution I've thought of is to treat the Phonegap Activity as a sort of pseudo-Service by spawning a "dummy" or empty Service (utilizing `startService` and `startForeground`). The idea is that the lifecycle of the Phonegap Activity will be tied to the lifecycle of the Service and will thus continue executing Javascript code in the background.

Regardless of whether you know Phonegap, my question is this: If I prioritize a process by spawning a foreground service within it, does this affect the Activity lifecycle? Is it possible that the service (and its process) stays alive and that the main Activity is cleared from memory?

If there is no guarantee that the Activity lifecycle is affected per say, can you say anything about what might happen in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One solution I've thought of is to treat the Phonegap Activity as a sort of pseudo-Service by spawning a "dummy" or empty Service (utilizing startService and startForeground).

If you can do that, you can implement the actual service in native Java code (rather than merely writing an empty service in native Java code), and you can avoid all this nonsense.

> The idea is that the lifecycle of the Phonegap Activity will be tied to the lifecycle of the Service and will thus continue executing Javascript code in the background.

AFAIK, `WebView` neither knows nor cares whether there is a `Service` in the process or not. There is no guarantee that `WebView` will continue executing JavaScript indefinitely when the `WebView` is not visible. And, since your PhoneGap app is pretty much just a `WebView`, it is this undocumented `WebView` behavior that you are relying upon.

> If I prioritize a process by spawning a foreground service within it, does this affect the Activity lifecycle? Is it possible that the service (and its process) stays alive and that the main Activity is cleared from memory?

The user is welcome to press the BACK button, destroying your activity, and that is unaffected by whether or not you started some service.

The user is welcome to use a task manager (e.g., recent tasks list on Android 4.0+) to shut down your background process, and that is unaffected by whether or not you started some service.

The user is welcome to force stop your app via Settings, to prevent your code from ever running again without their permission, and that is unaffected by whether or not you started some service.

The OS is welcome to terminate your process on its own -- `startForeground()` is not a lifetime pass.

All that being said, in those latter three scenarios, the activity and the service will go away in tandem, when the process does. Only the BACK button (or your calling `finish()`, or some unhandled exception) would cause the activity to go away but have the service linger on.

Comment: Thanks so much! Though, looking at the Phonegap source, it looks like the WebView is meant to keep running Javascript even after onPause is called. Being that the WebView is just a member of the DroidGap Activity, it seems to me that Javascript can continue to run in the background so long as the Activity exists.

Comment: @sfridman: You are welcome to point out where in the documentation it indicates that this behavior is to be expected and considered reliable.

Comment: Guys, it is not documented, but it is really what you want to expect in Cordova/PhoneGap. Otherwise, no logic except UI could be implemented abandoning the whole hybrid app idea.

Answer (score 1):

CommonsWare gave a good comprehensive answer. I'd like to augment it with my experience.

Yes, spawning a dummy service and calling `startForeground()` reliably kept my application running in background. I and my few users have never seen that OS killed the app on its own.

**BUT**, every time I manually terminate the activity (swipe it out from the Recents), the service gets also stopped. Though, in the context of PhoneGap it looks pretty logical.

Also, with PhoneGap, you can override the back button behavior as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5312426/65899).