# Plugin Phonegap Power Management

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried to install this plugin for android. But it didn't work :in my index.html

```
function acquire() {
        cordova.require('cordova/plugin/powermanagement').acquire(
                function() { alert( 'hooray' ); },
                function() { alert( 'oh no!' ); }
                );
    };
```

I have no alert :s

.  I put in the www folder ;

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/cordova/powermanagement.js">         </script>
```

then , in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and in my config.xml

```
<plugin name="PowerManagement" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.PowerManagement"/
```

what is wrong in my code?

Thanks.
Aurelie

Answer (score 7):

I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted. What version of Phonegap are you using?

I had to update the PowerManagement plugin [on github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/PowerManagement) to get it working with Cordova 2.8.0. I also extended it to be able to acquire a partial wakelock. You can download my Eclipse project containing the updated plugin [here](http://ge.tt/5ks6w1k/v/0).

Here's the updated code for use with Cordova 2.8.0:

**PowerManagement.java**

```
/*
   Copyright 2011-2012 Wolfgang Koller - http://www.gofg.at/

   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
*/

/**
 * Cordova (Android) plugin for accessing the power-management functions of the device
 * @author Wolfgang Koller <viras@users.sourceforge.net>
 */
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

/**
 * Plugin class which does the actual handling
 */
public class PowerManagement extends CordovaPlugin {
    // As we only allow one wake-lock, we keep a reference to it here
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = null;
    private PowerManager powerManager = null;

    /**
     * Fetch a reference to the power-service when the plugin is initialized
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);

        this.powerManager = (PowerManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        Log.d("PowerManagementPlugin", "Plugin execute called - " + this.toString() );
        Log.d("PowerManagementPlugin", "Action is " + action );

        try {
            if( action.equals("acquire") ) {                
                String type = args.optString(0);
                if(type.equals("dim") ) {
                    Log.d("PowerManagementPlugin", "Only dim lock" );
                    this.acquire( PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK );
                }
                else if(type.equals("partial") ) {
                    Log.d("PowerManagementPlugin", "Only partial lock" );
                    this.acquire( PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK );
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("PowerManagementPlugin", "Full wakelock" );
                    this.acquire( PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK );
                }
            }
            else if( action.equals("release") ) {
                this.release();
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            return false;
        }

        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Acquire a wake-lock
     * @param p_flags Type of wake-lock to acquire
     */
    private void acquire( int p_flags ) {

        if (this.wakeLock == null) {
            this.wakeLock = this.powerManager.newWakeLock(p_flags, "PowerManagementPlugin");
            try {
                this.wakeLock.acquire();
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {
                this.wakeLock = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Release an active wake-lock
     */
    private void release() {

        if( this.wakeLock != null ) {
            this.wakeLock.release();
            this.wakeLock = null;

        }
    }

    /**
     * Make sure any wakelock is released if the app goes into pause
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause(boolean multitasking) {
        if( this.wakeLock != null ) this.wakeLock.release();

        super.onPause(multitasking);
    }

    /**
     * Make sure any wakelock is acquired again once we resume
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {
        if( this.wakeLock != null ) this.wakeLock.acquire();

        super.onResume(multitasking);
    }
}
```

**powermanagement.js**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2012 Wolfgang Koller
 * 
 * This file is part of GOFG Sports Computer - http://www.gofg.at/.
 * 
 * GOFG Sports Computer is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * GOFG Sports Computer is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with GOFG Sports Computer.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/powermanagement", function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');

    var PowerManagement = function() {};

    /**
     * Acquire a full wake-lock (keep device awake)
     * 
     * @param successCallback function to be called when the wake-lock was acquired successfully
     * @param errorCallback function to be called when there was a problem with acquiring the wake-lock
     */
    PowerManagement.prototype.acquire = function(successCallback,failureCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'PowerManagement', 'acquire', []);
    }

    /**
     * Release the wake-lock
     * 
     * @param successCallback function to be called when the wake-lock was released successfully
     * @param errorCallback function to be called when there was a problem while releasing the wake-lock
     */
    PowerManagement.prototype.release = function(successCallback,failureCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'PowerManagement', 'release', []);
    }

    /**
     * Acquire a partial wake-lock, allowing the device to dim the screen
     *
     * @param successCallback function to be called when the wake-lock was acquired successfully
     * @param errorCallback function to be called when there was a problem with acquiring the wake-lock
     */
    PowerManagement.prototype.dim = function(successCallback,failureCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'PowerManagement', 'acquire', ["dim"]);
    }

    /**
     * Acquire a partial wake-lock, allowing the device to turn off the screen but keep the CPU active
     *
     * @param successCallback function to be called when the wake-lock was acquired successfully
     * @param errorCallback function to be called when there was a problem with acquiring the wake-lock
     */
    PowerManagement.prototype.partial = function(successCallback,failureCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'PowerManagement', 'acquire', ["partial"]);
    }


    var powermanagement = new PowerManagement();
    module.exports = powermanagement;
});
```

**index.html (for testing)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="powermanagement.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function deviceready() {
            alert( 'cordova ready!' );
        }

        function acquire() {
            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/powermanagement').acquire(
                    function() { alert( 'successfully acquired full wake lock' ); },
                    function() { alert( 'error acquiring full wake lock' ); }
                    );
        };

        function release() {
            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/powermanagement').release(
                    function() { alert( 'successfully released wake lock' ); },
                    function() { alert( 'error releasing wake lock' ); }
                    );
        }

        function dim() {
            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/powermanagement').dim(
                    function() { alert( 'successfully acquired dim wake lock!' ); },
                    function() { alert( 'error acquiring dim wake lock' ); }
                    );
        }

        function partial() {
            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/powermanagement').partial(
                    function() { alert( 'successfully acquired partial wake lock!' ); },
                    function() { alert( 'error acquiring partial wake lock' ); }
                    );
        }

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="acquire();">acquire</button>
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="release();">release</button>
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="dim();">dim</button>
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="partial();">partial</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . My cordova version is 2.7.0. The link for your elipse project doesn't work :s. Can I have the good one ;). So if is not the version of cordova the problem that's mean I have one in my code :s. I will try with your code.

Comment: The link still works for me - try again: [http://ge.tt/5ks6w1k/v/0](http://ge.tt/5ks6w1k/v/0)

Comment: I've tried twice. But now i got it ;) thanks a lot. I'll try with yours files.

Comment: ok I took your code and in eclipse I have a warning : Description Resource Path Location Type
The field PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated PowerManagement.java /projet/src/org/apache/cordova/plugin line 73 Java Problem   this is normal? Moreover the alert like in your code doesn 't work

Comment: this is my code the console.log doesn't howewer my function yes (GPS) :     if( (sexeSeek !== '') && (seek !== '') && (orientation !== '') && (age !== '') && (slider1 === 'on')) {
                watchInterval = true;
                watchPosition();
                   function acquire() {
            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/powermanagement').acquire(
                    function() { console.log( 'successfully acquired full wake lock' ); },
                    function() { console.log( 'error acquiring full wake lock' ); }
                    );
        };

Comment: It doesn't matter that PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated - it's just a warning and it will still work. The plugin code definitely works as I'm using it in my own apps. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed for Eclipse. [Here's screen capture](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/2559/6oz.png) of it running on my HTC HD2. Try [this APK](http://ge.tt/9lkx63k/v/0) which I compiled from my Eclipse project.

Comment: ok ok. Yes the apk works in my phone. I have Android 4.2.2 installed on Eclipse. I don't understand why nothing happened in my application. it was 2 days that I search why :s. I really sucks

Comment: I installed an other phongegap plugin for the in app purchase. Maybe the two plugins are not compatibles?

Comment: I would think it's unlikely that the plugins would interfere with each other. You could try commenting out the other one just to be sure. Look at the LogCat window in Eclipse when your app is running and make sure no errors are being logged - even a Javascript error could prevent the plugin being executed properly. Then cut back your application by commenting out functionality until you can isolate the problem.

Comment: okay I'll try this tomorrow I let you know if the problem come to that.

Comment: Hey, can you help me to install the power management plugin on iOs please?

Comment: I have a requirement in my cordova app to wake up the device when there is an event in my application. Suppose the user is using my application and has put the phone idle and it gets locked, Meanwhile there is an event happening in my app then I need to wake up the phone, I am using wakelock in cordova but it does not work.