# Run PhoneGap application in intervals

Tags: cordova

I am developing an application that should do some action at certain interval that can be defined by the user. I found out that it is not possible to create a service using PhoneGap, so is it possible to run certain code in intervals, like every 5 minutes. Is there possibly another solution that would allow me to do some action at the certain time?

Target platforms are Android & iOS

**Edit:**
My service should check user's geographic position every 5-15 minutes and send it to the server.

Comment: What are you looking to do exactly? Send push notifications on a specified interval? Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Could you see an update please? Does this help?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583866/how-to-track-the-device-location-ios-and-android-device-using-phonegap)?

Answer (score 0):

The core of PhoneGap is Cordova, so this answer may be useful:

[Cordova scheduling task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517871/cordova-scheduling-task/34430849#34430849)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement where I was supposed to capture the GPS location of a user every 10 seconds.

**Here is how I did it :**

Every 10 seconds I would capture the geolocation of the mobile phone user and put it in a SQLite database.

I would then run a function every 5 minutes which would batch upload the geolocation data from the SQLite database on device to the server.

I did this to reduce the amount of network calls being made to the server.

This caused a problem when the program went into background mode.
To get around that I used the background mode plugin : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode