# Always keep light on and disable phone lock - Phonegap

Tags: android, api, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an app using Cordova / Phonegap. I don't want the phone to turn off the light or lock itself.

My app needs the always light-on or never-lock mode functionality.

**How can I achieve that in Phonegap application?**

I searched for these functionality, found nothing. Do I need to write separate code for separate type of devices? Please help.....

Comment: You have to use some plugin. check this post might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250808/plugin-phonegap-power-management  @AtanuCSE

Comment: http://chris-allen-lane.com/2012/11/phonegap-prevent-an-android-devices-screen-from-sleeping/ check this also. @AtanuCSE

Comment: and for disabling the phone lock https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/7PX0DvrdPWw @AtanuCSE

Answer (score 1):

In Android you do this by adding following attribute in your layout:

```
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

You can add this to your root element.

I haven't used the PhoneGap for Android but you can try this:

Add the following permission in your Manifest:

```
"android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
```

Then in your activity add:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply bro, I know it'll work for android. I've seen this before. But I was expecting more like Phonegap solution, so that all devices(iphone/android) can be handled with single piece of code.Lets see if any other answers came.