# Installing Cordova "native" PowerManagement plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins

Where to download original cordova plugin for PowerManagement, and how to install it?
I am referring to this class org.apache.cordova.plugin.PowerManagement
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not official Cordova plugin

You could install in by using following command:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Viras-/cordova-plugin-powermanagement.git
```

Gihub for the plugin:
https://github.com/Viras-/cordova-plugin-powermanagement

Comment: the not official one is having class org.apache.cordova.powermanagement.PowerManagement , does the other without "powermanagement" namespace mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250808/plugin-phonegap-power-management exist?

Comment: Namespace was changed in this commit.
https://github.com/Viras-/cordova-plugin-powermanagement/commit/8b0c68770ff01af341710713aeaa57aa8d635fac

No other change happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one (not offical Cordova plugin, but referenced on cordova plugins site)

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.power

and it support android and ios.

Use the requestKeepAwake API to keep power on :

```
chrome.power.requestKeepAwake('display');
```

Then use the releaseKeepAwake API to turn off :

```
chrome.power.releaseKeepAwake();
```