# Keep Apache Cordova event listeners active on sleep mode

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, dom-events

I'm developing a simple music player app using Ionic framework and Apache Cordova. One of the goals of my app it's to allow user to switch songs using volume buttons (volumeup -> next song, volumedown -> prev song); I already achieved that but there's a problem : when the smartphone goes in stand by, for example if i press the lock button, the volume buttons start to work as default (volumeup -> increases the volume, volumedown -> decreases the volume). How can i prevent that? I know there are ways to prevent the standby mode, but I think a player that keeps the screen on, would cause a early battery low.

Comment: You will need a plugin to catch events when your app is running in background. You should give this a shot: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: Another option is to acquire a [partial wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) to keep your app active on the CPU, even if screen is off/locked. This can be done using a [plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250808/plugin-phonegap-power-management/17251197#17251197)