# GPS position when mobile app is in background (with ionicframework)

Tags: gps, ionic-framework

I need to realize an app that store user journey (path) when he moves from A to B. Now, I know that ionicframework can use GPS, but what happen when my APP go to background ? How can my app continue to store user position ? Is this possible ? Are there plugins (not $600+ please) that I can use ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386231/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-when-screen-is-locked

Comment: Nope, this is not a duplicate, that other answer is referencing a premium plugin @ZioBudda was mentioning

Answer (score 9):

I just finished writing a new cordova background geolocation plugin for ios and android, its free and simple! try it out:

https://github.com/pmwisdom/cordova-background-geolocation-services

Ionic Usage :

```
//Wait for cordova / ionic ready to use the plugin
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    //Make sure to get at least one GPS coordinate in the foreground before starting background services
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();

    //1. Get plugin
    var bgLocationServices =  window.plugins.backgroundLocationServices;

    //2. Configure Plugin
    bgLocationServices.configure({
         desiredAccuracy: 20, 
         distanceFilter: 5, 
         notificationTitle: 'BG Plugin', 
         notificationText: 'Tracking',
         debug: true, 
         interval: 9000, 
         fastestInterval: 5000
    });

    //3. Register a callback for location updates, this is where location objects will be sent in the background
    bgLocationServices.registerForLocationUpdates(function(location) {
         console.log("We got a BG Update" + JSON.stringify(location));
    }, function(err) {
         console.log("Error: Didn't get an update", err);
    });

    //4. Start the Background Tracker. When you enter the background tracking will start, and stop when you enter the foreground.
    bgLocationServices.start();


    ///later, to stop
    bgLocationServices.stop();

});
```

Comment: Please include some sample usage here.

Comment: What kind of sample usage would you like? The github repo shows usage details.

Comment: @Mirrorcell: Great Plugin...works like Charm.. :)
But my real concern is when user remove/kill app from list of last visted app(by pressing right most squre icon over android phone..It shows all listed) . It doesn't work. It suppose to work..like Whatsapp or GMap...Please correct me. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Niks, tracking does not work after the application has been force closed. How do WhatsApp and Google maps work in this way? If I force close Google Maps, for instance, the tracking stops on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with a plugin you're referring as a $600+ premium plugin.

People usually forget that older versions are also available, including last viable Android/iOS version: https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/tree/0.3.7

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-background-geolocation@1.0.5
```

Currently, other distinct versions do not exist, everything else is just a fork of this original plugin.

Comment: I'm trying to use your provided plugin for Background geolocation. But I'm getting notification flash as "Background Geolocation: INVALID LICENSE". Could you please help me out to fix it? Let me know if you need more info about my script. Thanks in-advance.