# How to check for location automatically?

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Geofire and Cordova Geolocation in my Ionic app like this :

```
//Catch the position of the user
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

        var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
   $cordovaGeolocation
   .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
   .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude

       var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
// Insert geofire location of userId
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('/geolocation/');
var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
geoFire.set(userId, [lat, long]).then(function() {

}, function(error) {

});
// end geofire
         firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).update({
       lat: lat,
       long: long,
       })
   }, function(err) {

   });
   var watchOptions = {timeout : 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
   var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
   watch.then(
      null,
      function(err) {

      },
      function(position) {
         var lat  = position.coords.latitude
         var long = position.coords.longitude

         var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
         firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).update({
       lat: lat,
       long: long,
       })
      }
   );
    watch.clearWatch();
    }
```

I try to have the location being automatically caught by the app when the user moves. For example, the user moves a few meters and that updates it with this code.

However I can not find a way to have it that way. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400335/gps-position-when-mobile-app-is-in-background-with-ionicframework

Comment: Hello, that is not what I am asking for. But thanks