# Steps to use GPS in IONIC Framework

Tags: gps, ionic-framework

i need to create an app in Ionic framework (using android) that enables GPS with a ion-toggle. I wonder if there're some tutorials or what are the steps that i must follow to create it. Thanks

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32386909/3901856

Comment: thanks im gonna check it out