# Why won't the Back button work in this Android webview?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-webview

Having problems getting the "Back" button to work in webview.

I'm not sure where in the code I should put the `onKeyDown()` part (currently under the last `@Override`)

Both `mywebview.canGoBack()` and `mywebview.goBack()` result in errors saying "mywebview cannot be resolved".

If I move the bracket after `mywebview.setWebClient(...)` all the way to the bottom, `mywebview-error` goes away, but then `override`, `onKeyDown`, `return true`, and `return super` result in all kind of errors.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Code:

```
package com.sib;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class SiB extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sib);

        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebview.loadUrl("url");

        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make `mywebview` a class instance variable.

```
public class SiB extends Activity {
WebView mywebview;
```

Then make sure to not shadow it by taking out the declaration in `onCreate()` It should look like this:

```
mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mywebview.loadUrl("url");
```

And based on [what I can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity), Gabe is right. `onKeyDown()` for back presses is only for API 4 and lower. `onBackPressed()` should work for everyting newer than API 4.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    if (mywebview.canGoBack()) {
        mywebview.goBack();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();      
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! both of you. got it working now! much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

onKeyDown doesn't work for back.  You need to override onBackPressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! got it working now! much appreciated