# Hardware back button on specific layout

Tags: android, back-button

i have this problem: I have lot of layout pages and each has a back button as a picture. That mean when you tap on that picture, you are redirect on layout sreen, which is previous. I have only two activity. That is achieve by this metod:

```
public void button2 
(View button) {setContentView(R.layout.screen1);}
```

Is there someone option like this for hardware back button? When i tap on hardware back button, it redirect me on specific layout page? I try option stated on this page: [How to handle back button in activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity)
but there not helped. Please can you hepled or explain? Thank you very much.

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfoCompat.CONFIG_UI_MODE);    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {   
return; }
```

when use these up, nothing happened.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    return true;    }
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    }
```

when use these, hardware back button cause return to main screen of the android telephone

Comment: Can you show us some code that isn't working? When you say that the link you provided didn't help, what does that mean? What happened when you tried those suggestions?

Comment: @Tanis.7x Sorry, code added. I tried options stated on these link and no one do what i need. Return on previous layout creen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually do something in `onBackPressed()`. Simply returning will result in exactly what you would expect from a method that does nothing: *nothing*.

If your Activity is a true second Activity, you can start in onBackPressed with an Intent like so:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, MyNextActivity.class);
    startActivity(nextActivity);
}
```

However, it looks like your second "Activity" might just be a different layout for the current Activity. In that case you can simulate a real Activity as so:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setContentView(R.layout.my_second_activity);
}
```

I would also recommend sticking with `onBackPressed()` instead of `onKeyDown()` unless you are targeting an API version less than 5.

Comment: Second option working. But if i have more layouts, exist some condition for recognize, on which one i press hardware button?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood that comment. The second option is working, correct? What do you mean by "Because i have two activity with lot of layout with text, exist some condition, which will be doing this?"

Comment: Maybe image can explain better: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/5/codem.png/                                                         I have only two activity, for redirecting to loayout using     public void.

Comment: If you want to keep that design pattern, you can add a "history" of layouts in an [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). Just add the layout ID every time the user selects one and pop a layout ID when back is pressed.

However, I would highly encourage you to follow a more standard design pattern and actually create an `Activity` for each of your "activities"