# How do i override back button in my activity?

Tags: android

I need to override back button in my activity to do a certain task. 
I want this code to be executed when the back button is pressed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainClass.class);
```

Comment: onBackPressed is availavle in your activity

Comment: -1 please do some research before posting questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: use it and read the lifecycle of the Activity

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle back button in activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainClass.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

Comment: Are you really serious to give answer on this post.

Comment: already did.Dont worry.

Comment: You should keep any one of the two lines.. super.onBackPressed or Calling Activity

Comment: Give the link from he/ she can read it in better way