# Back Key not working properly

Tags: android, back

I want to add the back key in my application so I added this

```
onCreate(){
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

And this

```
        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            this.finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

It works fine when i press the back button from the App But when I press physical back button key it kill the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override this,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the `back` button and `up` button. In your post you've mentioned about `up` button. See [Up vs Back](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back) in android documentation. For handling the `back` key, You might need to override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) in your activity to handle the situation. See [How to handle back button in activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity).