# Disable back, Home and Recent button in android programmatically

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am developing lock screen application in android.

The problem is how to disable Back, Home and Recent button in the activity?

I found that back button disable using:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }
```

But how to disable the others?

Problem image: http://postimg.org/image/a0tnk7kr5/

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `Back` action and return `true` to let the OS know that this action already handled and prevent executing the default action for that, which is closing the screen

Your code is valid for API level 5, but for older then API 5 use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // your code
    return true;
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

reference: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5312391/1364896)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android) question is asking about how to disable the *Home and Recent* buttons like the **MXPlayer** application when you click on the Lockscreen. The accepted answer says that

> Since you cannot override the Home button on Android device (at least
>   no in the latest OS versions). MX Player draws itself on top of your
>   launcher when you "lock" the app and clicks on the Home button.

and gives a details description how to do that. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20945431/1364896)

Comment: Problem image: http://postimg.org/image/a0tnk7kr5/

i want to disable this two button

Comment: But in same lockscreen app i found that developer disable it...if any other help please, suggest me...

Comment: @RankMayur check my updated answer. It is possible but might takes some efforts from you, dude

Comment: Check out this link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20945431/1364896). It describe in details how to do that @RankMayur

Comment: @RankMayur You are welcome. If you find my answer useful please accept it as the Answer and vote it up. Happy coding

Answer (score -2):

Actually it is a problem with your touch screen
Even your screen parts are working
You can download (button savior) app
It will add you a extra back home and recent button to your mobile