# How to Identify the device down button listener in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, keyboard-events

I am add the edittext to my signup Form .I tounch the edittext shows  the focus and display the keyboard.But i want to hide the keyboard.I did not get the any listner.
please see the below screenshot

[image]

How can i identify the above listener in fragment .Because ,i want to clear the focus to edittext.please tell me anyone know .Advance thanks to all

Comment: I think you get this event in onBackPressed().

Answer (score 0):

And when is the keyboard suppose to appear so you can enter some input in the EditText? You can add this to your activity.

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

More info here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: thanks for ur reply.I want device down button listener

Comment: Check this answer and see if is this you're looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5312391/2517796)

Comment: I am using the fragment .but above is not device back button

Comment: Tell me exactly what you wan to do. You want to disable the keyboard when it loses focus from the edittext? For example when you click outside the edittext the keyboard should come down. Is that it?

Comment: no,i want to clear focus of edittext click on the device down button.