# Android Webview make back button go to previous page

Tags: android

I have a web view that lets me browse through a site. When i click the back button, rather than it going to the previous page it exits the app. I have added the following method to MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webview.canGoBack()) {
                    webview.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle back button in activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6077141/6521116)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you should override your activity `OnBackPressed` :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not override `onKeyDown` event, override `onBackPressed`, so that every time the back button is pressed, you can override it and add your own logic into it. The Code is like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full reference for next button and progress bar : [put back and next button in webview](https://demonuts.com/webview-back-forward/)

If you want to go to back page when click on phone's back button, use this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

You can also create custom back button like this:

```
btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (wv.canGoBack()) {
                wv.goBack();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Backkey pressed event is not suitable here use this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent=new Intent(LiveImage.this,DashBoard.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```