# notification directing to the middle of an app

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have an app with 3 activities:

MainActivity
ActivityOne
ActivityTwo

I set the parent of ActivityOne is MainActivity and of ActivityTwo is ActivityOne in the manifest xml file

I created a button in the main activity that trigger a notification, when I click the notification, it directs me to ActivityTwo..

what I want to do is, when I click back button in the navigation bar it directs me to ActivityOne, and when I click it again, it directs me to MainActivity

I wan't to be able to do this, while the app is not running at the begginning, i.e using taskStackBuilder

I have been trying like for ever, but still in vain.

Comment: You can start ActivityOne from notification and start ActivityTwo from ActivityOne. Both activities must be started. Or you can handle back button press from ActivityTwo to start ActivityOne.

Comment: is there away to set on click listener for the back button?
this is what you meant, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity